# How to know the number of pages in a PDF file?

Tags: graphics, pdf, page-numbering

I use `graphicx` to include pages of a PDF file. I want to know in LaTeX how many pages are in the file. How to do this?

Comment: @Mathew wouldn't a simplistic solution be to insert a counter variable just before the includegraphics and after and get the difference?

Comment: @Yiannis, the topic starter is @fillieule. :-)

Comment: @xport Oops! yannis_was_sleeping!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

pdfpages is obviously somehow able to get the number of pages of an included pdf. It does it with the pdftex primitive `\pdflastximagepages`. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \pdfximage{test.pdf}%
  \the\pdflastximagepages
\end{document}
```

### Update 2022

There is also an expl3 function which works with all backends:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3graphics}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\graphics_get_pagecount:nN{example-image-duck.pdf}\l_tmpa_tl
\l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX?