# how to import a whole PDF as a figure

Tags: graphics, floats, pdfpages

I know how to include single pages of one document as images in another document.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-100]
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\page[1]{
  \frame{\includegraphics[page=#1, scale=.2]{file.pdf}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \page{1}\page{2} \\
  \page{3}\page{4}
  \caption{Pages}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I struggle with including the whole `file.pdf` without knowing how many pages it consists of.

I already tinkered with `pdfpages` to replace `graphicx`, but have difficulties of containing the imported pages in the floating environment then. Wrapping `\includepdf` into a `minipage` does not alleviate this problem.

How can I display the pages of a pdf in a figure?

Comment: What is `\frame`? The `beamer` frame command?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\frame` just puts a border around the pdf content so they are more clearly recognizable as pages against the white background.

Comment: What about `\includepdf` ?

Comment: @RomainPicot see the paragraph about `pdfpages`. It seems `\includepdf` does not like to be put into floats.

Comment: @XZS Yes, but where does `\frame` come from?

Comment: @XZS: Please make a working example instead of fragments.

Comment: You should edit to put the complete MWE with the preamble you used `;-)`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer From this answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20715/17129 That is all I know about it...

Comment: MWE now complete with file.tex.

Comment: With `\includepdf` this might be a layout issue only

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\includepdf` seems to hog the whole page to itself, overlaying the caption, surrounding text and ignoring any positioning, to only name a few problems. I am open to an `\includepdf` solution, if you manage to find one.

Comment: it's not clear, is each page of your document only one figure of 4 pages with caption `pages`? nothing else?

Comment: @touhami The figure should be part of a much bigger document. I left out the surrounding text in the MWE here. All pages of the included `file.pdf` should end up inside the same `figure`. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: ok, use a new document tempfile.tex like this `\documentclass{scrartcl} \usepackage{pdfpages} \begin{document} \includepdf[nup=4x6,frame,pages=-]{file.pdf} \end{document}` you can use 6x6 or whatever to make all `file.pdf`'s pages in one page pdf file and than use it with `\includegraphics`

Comment: @touhami: you should answer this question!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer please, if you think so you can make it an answer, you can add some explanation that make it more helpfull than I can.

Comment: @touhami: No, you've found the `nup=...` option -- I did not find it in the manual (however, I did not test your suggestion)

Comment: see this related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/how-to-know-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file and you can use the option height rather then scale.