# Get number of pages of an inserted .pdf file

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages, foreach

I wish to insert all pages of `myFigures.pdf` in a row with:

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,6} {%
    \includegraphics[page=\i]{myFigures.pdf}%
}
```

How do I make this code adaptive to the actual number of pages in `.pdf` file, which may be more or less than `6` one day?
I am looking for something like:

```
% How to retrieve that information?
\def\nbPages{\numberOfPagesIn{myFigures.pdf}}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\nbPages} {%
    \includegraphics[page=\i]{myFigures.pdf}%
}
```

Comment: you can use `\includepdf` from the pdfpages package to include the whole file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The truth is that I need to include them on differents slides in a tikz / beamer, with something like `\foreach \i in {1,...,\nbPages} {\node<\i> at \myCoords{\i} {\includegraphics[page=\i]{myFigures.pdf}};}`. Would `\includepdf` really help then? I just need `\nbPages`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8324/2388 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198091/get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes! This is what I needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdftex has the following primitive to return the page count (from the manual, page 34)

> ```
> \pdflastximagepages (read--only integer)
> ```
>
> This read--only register returns the highest page number from a file previously accessed via the
>        \pdfximage command. This is useful only for pdf files; it always returns 1 for png, jpeg, or jbig2 files.

It might be easier to look at the usage in the pdfpages and see how it uses its `last` key, but this is the basic primitive.

---

In a nutshell, the command you miss is:

```
\pdfximage{myFigures.pdf}
\def\nbframes{\the\pdflastximagepages}
```

see this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8324/2388).

Comment: Yeah.. so, once I have retrieved this `read--only integer` with `\def\nbp{\pdfximage{myFigures.pdf}\pdfrefximage\pdflastximagepages}`, how may I use it as an actual number? Using it in `{1,...,\nbp}` leads to `Missing number`. Using it as plain text in `plain \LaTeX \nbp{} text` produces.. a little book icon?! .. I am still missing `\def\nbPages{\THISCOMMAND{\nbp}}`.